# How can I deeply map over object with Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm trying to find all "template values" e.g. `{ template: 'Date: <now>'}` using a map function to get this basic behaviour:

```
deepMap(mapFn, {a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: { template: 'Date: <now>'}}})

>> {a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: 'Date: 13423234232'}}
```

This is what I have so far. The interpolation of the template object *does* happen, but it does not replace the value.

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: { template: 'Date: <now>'}}};

const deepMap = (fn, xs) =>
  mapObjIndexed(
    (val, key, obj) =>
      or(is(Array, val), is(Object, val))
        ? deepMap(fn, fn(val)) 
        : fn(val),
    xs
  );

const checkFn = ({ template }) => template;
const transformFn = (val, key) => {
  const interpolated = val.template.replace('<now>', Date.now())
  console.log(interpolated);
  return interpolated;
};

const mapFn = n =>
  checkFn(n)
    ? transformFn(n)
    : n;
console.clear();
deepMap(mapFn, obj);

>> {"a": 1, "b": {"c": 2, "d": {}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `deepMap` on the mapped value again - but the mapped value isn't an object anymore, but a string.

```
or(is(Array, val), is(Object, val))
        ? deepMap(fn, fn(val)) 
        : fn(val),
```

In case val is `{ template: 'Date: <now>'}`, val is an object and could be deep-mapped, but `fn(val)` is a String (`"Date: 123123123"`) which should simply be returned. One solution is to make the `is` checks on the mapped value, not the original value:

```
(val, key) => {
      const mappedVal = fn(val);
      return or(is(Array, mappedVal), is(Object, mappedVal))
        ? deepMap(fn, mappedVal) 
        : mappedVal;
 },
```

Another possibility would be to check whether the map-function returned something else than the original value and don't recurse in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```js
const {map, has, is} = R

const transformTemplate = ({template}) => template.replace('<now>', Date.now())

const deepMap = (xs) => map(x => has('template', x) 
  ? transformTemplate(x)
  : is(Object, x) || is(Array, x)
    ? deepMap(x)
    : x, xs)

const result = deepMap({a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: { template: 'Date: <now>'}}})
// => {a: 1, b: {c: 2, d: "Date: 1542046789004"}}

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

If you wanted to pass in the transformation function, you can change it slightly to

```
const deepMap = (transformer, xs) => map(x => has('template', x) 
  ? transformer(x)
  : is(Object, x) || is(Array, x)
    ? deepMap(transformer, x)
    : x, xs)

const result = deepMap(transformTemplate, {a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: { template: 'Date: <now>'}}})
```

And of course you can wrap that in `curry` if you like.

I don't have time right now to investigate why this approach, which looks right at first glance, doesn't work.  I'm hoping it's something simple:

```
const deepMap = map(cond([
  [has('template'), transformTemplate],
  [is(Object), deepMap],
  [is(Array), deepMap],
  [T, identity]
]))
```